# Printf is not displaying a string

Tags: c

So, i got a small bug here. Why isnt printf displaying the second string?

```
printf("Player 1: ");          //asks the players names
    fgets(name1, 30, stdin);
printf("Player 2: ");
    fgets(name2, 30, stdin);
fulfil(table);
player=choose_player();
shows(table);
int i;
for (i=0, count=player; i<9; i++)
{
    if (count==1)
        printf("It's your turn, %s \n", name1);
    else
        printf("It's your turn, %s \n", name2);
```

(..)
 Output:

Player 1: David Lopes

Player 2: Ruben Amorim
(...)

It's your turn, David Lopes

It's your turn, __________

why isnt it showing the second name?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Since im new to programing, and new to this forum, dont expect much from me! :S Im leaving here the main function(can't post the entire code, because it is too big), so that you guys can have a feel of what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PLAYER1 88      //ASCII tabble 88='X'
#define PLAYER2 79      //ASCII table 79='O'

void intro();
int read ();
void fulfill(int v[]);
int control (int num1, int table[]);
int control_victory(int line[]);
int choose_player();
int show(int table[]);

int main (void)
{
char name1[30], name2[30];
int table[8], num, w, player, contador, k;
intro();
printf("Player 1: ");          //Asks the names
    fgets(name1, 30, stdin);
printf("Player 2: ");
    fgets(name2, 30, stdin);
fulfill(table);
player=choose_player();
show(table);
int i;
for (i=0, contador=player; i<9; i++)
{
    if (contador==1)
        printf("It's your turn, %s \n", name1);
    else if (contador==2)
        printf("It's your turn, %s \n", name2);
    w=read();
    if (w==(-1))                           //if the user enters '0', the program will exit
        break;
    if (contador==1)
    {
        int verf;
        k=control (w, table);          //verifies if the number inserted is valid
        table[k]=PLAYER1;               //Inserts the char on the array
        show(table);              //presents a new table
        verf=control_victory(table);     //verifies if there is victory for the player 1
        if (verf==1)                    //
        {
            printf("\n%s won the game!\n", name1);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (verf==3)
            printf("\n Draw!\n");
        contador++;
    }
    else if (contador==2)      //Same here applies for player 2
    {
        int verf;
        k=control (w, table);          
        table[k]=PLAYER2;
        show(table);
        verf=control_victory(table);
        if (verf==2)
        {
            printf("\n%s won the game!\n", name2);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (verf==3)
            printf("\n Draw!\n");

        contador--;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: How are `name1` and `name2` defined?

Comment: Also you should try to debug your code yourself. On the how to do the latter you might like to read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: not enough code , please post your complete function with defines.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is meant to only display one of the two names at the same time.

The `else` keyword will not work if your first `if` is true
However, it should work on the second turn of the loop, when `count != 1`